# Failed to introduce Friendship in wechaty

Tags: javascript, node.js, wechaty

I introduced Friendship directly, but it failed. I don’t know if the js I used has anything to do with it. How can I use this class correctly?

```js
import {
  ScanStatus,
  WechatyBuilder,
  log,
  Friendship
} from 'wechaty'
```

The error reported is as follows:

```
The requested module 'wechaty' does not provide an export named 'Friendship'
```

I checked the documentation, but it’s not written in the documentation, and I can’t find it even if I search for it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to write in English so we can help you.

Comment: [segmentfault](https://segmentfault.com/) seems to be an unofficial Chinese language version of stackoverflow.

Comment: I modified this question